# Glib casting macros

Tags: c, casting, glib

Gtk has casting macros that allow it to change a gtk object's type:

```
GTK_WIDGET(gtktoolbox);
```

Glib works in a similar way (As far as I can tell) but I can't find the macros for data types:

```
G_INT(); // doesn't work
GINT(); // doesn't work
// etc
```

What are the glib casting macros? Or should I just use `(type) variable` instead?

I thought the whole point of these macros was to make that less risky? Or did that only apply to gtk objects because of their complex type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GTK+ uses some magic to do dynamic type checking and type safe casts. 
http://openbooks.sourceforge.net/books/wga/gtk.html#AEN194
This works for the GTK objects, but not for primitive types, like int. Just use `(int) var` instead.